# Adding Database Model (Database First Approach) in .NET Core class Library

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-class-library

I am adding Data Model (Database First Approach) in .NET Core Class Library using Entity FrameWorkCore.

I have added all necessary packages and when I try to create the model using below command using PMC I am receiving below message:

> "No project was found. Change the current working directory or use the --project option."

Command in PMC (using Core Class library):

```
dotnet ef dbcontext Scaffold "Server=XXX;Database=EFCore;User Id=XX;Password=XX;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models
```

Comment: have you referenced your class library to a runnable project like web application or console application?

Comment: I'm guessing you did not pick a project from the "Default Project" drop down.

Comment: Hi Arvind, Yes, I have referenced the project to my web api project... but still same problem

Comment: Hi William, Yes did select default project.. first tried to execute the command with class library project and result same

Comment: I am able to generate the models using command "Scaffold-DbContext" but not able to generate Stored Procedures or Views... any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "DataSource=D:\Database\SQLite\Example.sqlite" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite -OutputDir Model
```

[Tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx)